# Update several hundred thousand rows in psql

Tags: python, postgresql

I have dict consisting of about 450 000 entries, like this:

```
{'id1': 123, 'id2': 234, ..., 'id3': 567}
```

For each row in the dictionary I need to perform an update in a postgres DB. For executing one row my sql statement looks like this:

```
UPDATE employee.ids set "idNr" = <val> where "id" LIKE '%<id>%';
```

My issue is finding an efficient way to do this. To execute 450 000 single queries will probably take forever, so is there any way to do this efficiently?

Comment: have you tried bulk update ?

Comment: You can't have the same key multiple times in a dictionary.

Comment: Edited my answer :) The ids are unique.

Comment: could you use `https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sqlitedict` sqlitedict instead? It lets you access your database via the python dictionary API

Comment: @eqzx I don't think a library designed for SQLite works with PostgreSQL database.

Comment: @kennytm right. the database would need to be migrated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since PostgreSQL can handle json from version 9.3, if you are using that version or a newer one you can update the values with a single query, passing the dictionary as a json parameter.

The query should look like this:

```
update employee e set idnr = a.value::text::int8
from
json_each('{"id1": 123, "id2": 234, "id3": 567}'::json) a
where a.key = e.id
```

I think this approach will be much faster. And from version 9.4 jsonb is also supported. That can be a little bit faster, however I don't think it will make too much difference.
The query with jsonb looks like this:

```
update employee e set idnr = a.value::text::int8
from
jsonb_each('{"id1": 123, "id2": 234, "id3": 567}'::jsonb) a
where a.key = e.id
```